# Spring Security deploy failed: The lifecycle method [initialize] must not throw a checked exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-security, glassfish

I'm trying to develop a small web application with Spring and Hibernate JPA running on Glassfish server. Now I want to configure Spring Security but I'm getting errors while deploying. Here's Glassfish stack:

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   Error in annotation processing: {0}.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:585)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    ... 62 more

Severe:   The lifecycle method [initialize] must not throw a checked exception
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [MyLibrary]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The lifecycle method [initialize] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] on annotated element [protected void org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.initialize() throws java.lang.Exception] of type [METHOD]
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: The lifecycle method [initialize] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PostConstruct()] on annotated element [protected void org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.initialize() throws java.lang.Exception] of type [METHOD]
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:626)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The lifecycle method [initialize] must not throw a checked exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.handlers.AbstractResourceHandler.validateAnnotatedLifecycleMethod(AbstractResourceHandler.java:186)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.handlers.PostConstructHandler.processAnnotation(PostConstructHandler.java:72)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.handlers.AbstractResourceHandler.processAnnotation(AbstractResourceHandler.java:142)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344)
    ... 59 more
...
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MyLibrary</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/index" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDao" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Spring Security -->  
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
    </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

UserDao.java

```
package dao;

import ...

@Repository
public class UserDao implements UserDetailsService {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="LibraryPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public User getUserByLogin(String username) {
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM User e WHERE e.username LIKE :userLogin")
                                   .setParameter("userLogin", username);
        try {
            return (User) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch(NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = getUserByLogin(username);
        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);

        UserDetails ud = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
        return ud;
    }


}
```

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug in Glassfish. See [Cannot deploy simple project on Glassfish 3.1.2 and 4.0.0+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1355) for an additional information.

Probably you have an old version of Glassfish. Looks like this bug has fixed [TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy deploying Spring Boot application](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21265).